# Stepping through three or more numeric sequences

Tags: algorithm

Suppose you are supplied with three different streams of monotonically increasing numbers. You know nothing about them and they might very well be random. How would *you* write Python code to watch for the first occurrence of three matching numbers?

I realise that this is a generalisation of one early Project Euler (PE) problem. But it seems harder. If it's another problem on PE or some other such site then please tell me so that I won't expect an answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Disagree with (too broad) close votes, it's a pretty specific question.

Comment: It might be specific enough for a site like Programming Puzzles & Code Golf, but not specific enough for SO.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 It *is* specific enough for S.O., it's just that it's tagged improperly since it really has nothing to do with Python (aside from asking for code in Python). I would suggest the algorithm tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty straightforward: assuming you're given three iterators, always advance the one that has the lowest current value. At each advance, check the new item against the "current" values of the rest. Generalizes to any number of iterators, doesn't need any extra memory beyond one-item-per-iter.